# Jitpack - unable to import android library

Tags: android, github, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, jitpack

I forked a public MediaPicker library and forked it on Github. After making some changes to the library, I made a release of the project. I checked JitPack which is showing all ok for the release but I am still unable to import it. Following is the library url for JitPack

https://jitpack.io/#rohankandwal/MediaPicker/2.3.4

I have checked my root Gradle's setting and made sure that I have following lines added-

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

I tried importing the library by using following code -

`compile 'com.github.rohankandwal:MediaPicker:2.3.4'`

or

`compile 'com.github.rohankandwal:libary:2.3.4'`

I have also asked another developer to import library but he is also unable to do so, please advice what am I missing ? The Github link to library is 
https://github.com/rohankandwal/MediaPicker

Comment: Does the library build successfully on JitPack's CI servers?

Comment: ah it does. sorry

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44629080/jitpack-failed-to-resolve-subrepo

Comment: try [`compile 'com.github.rohankandwal:mediapickerexample:2.3.4'`](https://github.com/rohankandwal/MediaPicker/commit/0d7bb81c983fb32da22c4e539172bf3391742d61)

Comment: @Ibrahim Still not importing

Comment: @blackpanther Any idea how to resolve this?

Comment: @k3b I don't think it applies to my problem, can you help?

Comment: @RohanKandwal were you able to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Just replace this from :

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

to:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
           maven { 
    name "jitpack"
    url "https://jitpack.io" 
}
    }
```

Happy coding!!